Android application updates with on demand feature delivery
I have an android App with an on demand delivery module.
If I have a subset of users download the on demand module, and in the next version, I make changes in my on demand module,
do I need to write code so the on demand module of these users updates? Or will they get the new version of the on demand module when they pick up the new app update?
